# Retrieve a specific collection from firebase database with React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

building an application that retrieves data from firebase once a products barcode has been scanned and displays it in a flatList, however i am finding trouble with retrieving a specific collection by Id that is equal to the barcode ID from firebase, instead it is displaying the entire document

```
  handleBarCodeScanned = ({ type, data }) => {
    this.setState({ scanned: true });
  

    
      firebase
        .database()
        .ref('items')
        .once("value", (item) => {
          var li = [];

          item.forEach((child) => {
            li.push({
              key: child.key,
              itemName: child.val().itemName,
              itemPrice: child.val().itemPrice,
            });
          });
          this.setState({ list: li });
          console.log(item.toJSON());


        });
```

So i tried to hard code the collection Id by using the if statement and it works but i want it to retrieve the collection id from the database.

```
if (data == 6001374025686) {
      firebase
        .database()
        .ref('items')
        .orderByKey()
        .equalTo("6001374025686")
        .once("value", (item) => {
          var li = [];

          item.forEach((child) => {
            li.push({
              key: child.key,
              itemName: child.val().itemName,
              itemPrice: child.val().itemPrice,
            });
          });
          this.setState({ list: li });
          console.log(item.toJSON());


        });
    } else if (data == 3607342734074) {
      firebase
        .database()
        .ref('items')
        .orderByKey()
        .equalTo("3607342734074")
        .once("value", (item) => {
          var li = [];

          item.forEach((child) => {
            li.push({
              key: child.key,
              itemName: child.val().itemName,
              itemPrice: child.val().itemPrice,
            });
          });
          this.setState({ list: li });
          console.log(item.toJSON());
```

I hope my issue is clear
Please help.

[Database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLKSq.png)

[outPut of second approach 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhxWH.png)

[output of 1st approach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f75mn.png)

Comment: Can you please show the structure of the database folders and the output of both approaches?

Comment: i have edited the post please check the for the output of each approach now

Comment: we have same issue you solved please post anwer !!